# Initializing an Interface between two Activities is not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set an `Interface` between a `PreferenceActivity` and `MainActivity`
But I keep getting this null pointer error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.muddii.shoplist.settingactivity.SettingsChangedListener.onValutaChanged()' on a null object reference`

As I understand, when initializing an `Interface` to be used between two Activities, then you have to cast the `Interface` to the `Activity` implementing it as I have done: `settingsChangedListener = (SettingsChangedListener) getParent();`

And parent is the MainActivity where PrefActivity is started from. MainActivity is never destroyed so why is the interface object null?
I have also flagged `MainActivity` as parent for `PrefActivity` in the `Manifest`

**PrefActivity:**

```
public class PrefActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

SettingsChangedListener settingsChangedListener;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    //initializing the interface here. Parent is MainActivity
    settingsChangedListener = (SettingsChangedListener) getParent();


    editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(VALUTA_KEY);
    listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference(SORT_KEY);
    themecolorList = (ListPreference) findPreference(THEME_KEY);

    editTextPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    themecolorList.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `getParent()` returns something useful. It will always return `null`, in any modern Android app. When Activity A starts Activity B, A is not B's parent.

Comment: How would I then initialize an interface for an Activity in this case? I have seen other examples where getParent(); is replaced with context

Comment: @Muddz: You wouldn't. Activities, like Web pages, are largely independent. Most likely, your `MainActivity` should watch for preference changes and react to those. "I have seen other examples where getParent(); is replaced with context" -- not between activities, you haven't.

Comment: So I assume that I have to start this PrefActivity with `startActivityForResult()` instead, to get notified of changes that happends in PrefActivity

Comment: @Muddz: You could have the `MainActivity` watch for preference changes and react to those, as I mentioned in my previous comment. Or, `MainActivity` could simply re-load data from the preferences in `onStart()`, as it is coming back to the foreground. `startActivityForResult()` is not necessary.